# a verb that means inhabiting the desert by large numbers?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

I want to know if "conquer the desert" is the right way to talk about inhabiting desert by ***large numbers***.Also,if there is any other verb that can be used other than "conquer" like "invade" or "overrun".

EX:To face the problem of overpopulation,it is necessary to **conquer the desert**.

P.S:A verb that doesn't refer to a negative or militaristic meaning.

Comment: Would the word you're looking for work for things other than the desert? Like, say, the plains or the forest?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for something with a connotation of military action or conflict?

Comment: @Scott:No.Quite the contrary actually.I want it to be used in a way that does not refer to any negative or military meaning.

Comment: Well, “invade” sounds very militaristic, “conquer” seems to be primarily conflict-oriented, and, while “overrun” has technical meanings (similar to “overflow”), it also suggests aggression.  Yet your question features these three words.  If you don’t want to channel answers in that direction, you might want to demilitarize the question.   Did you try to use a thesaurus?

Comment: @Scott:I tried Cambridge's smart thesaurus but it didn't help.Anyways,can you find any verb that doesn't sound militaristic?

Comment: Well, “settle” and “colonize” occurred to me immediately when I read the question, but other people had already posted them as answers by then.  “Occupy” and “move in” might not meet your needs exactly, but perhaps they could be used as jumping-off points (i.e., search for synonyms for *them*).  I realize that your question says “inhabiting … by large numbers”, but if the “large numbers” requirement is important enough to disqualify words like “settle”, it would be helpful if you emphasized that in the question. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Consider also “permeate”; it’s not literally applicable to what you’re asking for, but might be acceptable as a metaphor.  Also, it would be nice if you would answer @Mitch’s question —not by responding in comments; but by [edit]ing your question to make it clearer and more complete.   Also unclear: you ask for “any other verb”, but you have used the [idioms] tag.

Comment: @Scott I think the OP simply wants to avoid unnecessarily negative connotations in the metaphor. So 'colonize' or 'occupy' might not be the best, but 'settle' is probably what they want. to get more of a connotation of  doing a lot of that... well there are lots of ways of saying that but not necessarily in a single word.

Comment: @Mitch: Did you make a typo (or a copy & paste error)?  The OP has accepted “colonize”/“colonise” and rejected “settle”.

Comment: @Scott No C&P error. 'Settle' is less tendentious than 'colonize'. I'm not psychic so I can't tell you why the OP accepted the more aggressive 'colonize'.

Comment: @Scott First of all,I am sorry for any inconvenience as this is the 3rd time I post a question on a forum(BTW I didn't know that OP stands for original poster before today).As for why I accepted colonize over settle through because although the both give the "inhabiting the desert" meaning only colonize give this "large number" meaning.(I checked from online examples and different trustful dictionaries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To face the problem of overpopulation, it is necessary to *colonise*
>   the desert.

*Colonise/colonize* generally has the same sense of acquisition by power as *conquer*, but adds the element of human settlement that *conquer* lacks. In the above example, it would even be an appropriate term in the broader ecological sense of how the human species responds to population pressure.

> **[colonize](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colonize)**
>   (*British* **colonise**)
>
> 1. Send settlers to (a place) and establish political control over it.
>      1.1 Settle among and establish control over (the indigenous people of an area)
>      1.2 Appropriate (a place or domain) for one's own use.
>      1.3 *Ecology*: (of a plant or animal) establish itself in (an area)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.So,can "conquer" or "invade" be used as well?

Comment: *Invade* is ok, but *conquer* would only be appropriate if you were being metaphorical, since it means "defeating an enemy".

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could say: *to settle throughout the desert*?

Comment: Maybe but it doesn't give the meaning of large numbers settling in the desert.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanEltaher I’d respectfully disagree. But I’m glad you feel your question has been answered.

Comment: :I definitely benefited from your answer so thanks for taking the time to help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

"pioneer the desert"

"Furthermore, as these populations increase, they will actually **pioneer the desert** and that is why so many people are needed, not so many tractors or machines." - Arne Garvi eden-foundation.org